# Setting up alternate routes to blocked sites via Wi-Fi in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, routing, wireless-networking

My office has restricted access to Internet sites such as Skype & Dropbox. I also have access to an unrestricted Wi-Fi.

The laptop is connected to both access points. Now my problem is, when `en0` (ethernet) is my preferred channel then blocked sites like Skype won’t work though I have an active Wi-Fi connection. If I change the preferred channel to `en1` (Wi-Fi) then Skype works but I cannot browse any of the company Intranet sites.

Why does the fallback to Wi-Fior visa versa does not work?

Here are my routing table entries using command `netstat -nr`:

```
$netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:

Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.2.1        UGSc           39        0     en1
default            172.16.8.1         UGScI           1        0     en0
default            link#15            UCSI            1        0    en16
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3   151103     lo0
169.254/30         link#15            UC              0        0    en16
169.254            link#11            UCS             0        0     en1
169.254            link#5             UCSI            0        0     en0
169.254            link#15            UCSI            2        0    en16
169.254.0.1        42:6f:2a:c8:db:89  UHLSW           5    47567    en16    648
169.254.0.2/32     link#15            UCS             0        0    en16
169.254.0.3        ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWb           0        9    en16
172.16.8/23        link#5             UCS             4        0     en0
172.16.8.1/32      link#5             UCS             1        0     en0
172.16.8.1         68:5:ca:10:18:5    UHLWIir         3        0     en0   1191
172.16.8.59        0:19:99:88:46:83   UHLWI           0        2     en0   1164
172.16.8.222       3c:97:e:cc:ff:de   UHLWI           0        0     en0   1167
172.16.9.100       3c:97:e:cb:e6:c6   UHLWI           0       68     en0   1169
172.16.9.233/32    link#5             UCS             1        0     en0
172.16.9.233       0:25:0:a4:fa:de    UHLWI           0        3     lo0
172.16.9.255       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        9     en0
192.168.2          link#11            UCS             2        0     en1
192.168.2.1/32     link#11            UCS             2        0     en1
192.168.2.1        74:31:70:6f:c6:58  UHLWIir        40       87     en1   1080
192.168.2.104/32   link#11            UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.2.105      0:27:10:93:24:30   UHLWI           0        0     en1   1168
192.168.2.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       10     en1
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0       67    en16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this route to your setup:

```
sudo route -n add <REPLACE WITH YOUR OFFICE SUBNET eg 172.16.8.0/24> <REPLACE WITH YOUR OFFICE GATEWAY eg 172.16.8.1> -interface en0
```

If this will not work you can delete it. Replace the x's.

```
sudo route -n delete x.x.x.x/24 x.x.x.x
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not work.  Moreover my original question was, why the network manager is not smart enough and when it is not then what is the advantage of keeping two parallel internet connection open?